# using clang v3.4 to compile a c/c++ source file for arm on ubuntu_x86-64

Tags: c++, c, arm, clang

## platform:

ubuntu14.04_x86-64

clang v3.4

## problem

since I can use command `clang -target i386 hello.c` to compile hello.c, I tried to use

`clang -target arm hello.c` ,

`clang -target armv7 hello.c` ,

`clang -target armv7-a hello.c`,

`clang -target arm-eabi hello.c`

to compile hello.c for ARM but all failed.

is there any information about the target types that clang supports?

```
$ clang -target arm-none-eabi hello.c
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:1: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.syntax'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:2: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.cpu'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:3: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.eabi_attribute'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:4: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.eabi_attribute'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:5: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.eabi_attribute'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:6: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.eabi_attribute'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:7: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.eabi_attribute'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:8: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.eabi_attribute'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:9: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.eabi_attribute'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:16: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{r11'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:17: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:18: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:19: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:20: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r11'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:21: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,.LCPI0_0'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:22: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[sp'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:23: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:24: Error: no such instruction: `bl printf'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:25: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r1,[sp,'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:26: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[sp'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:27: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:28: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:29: Error: invalid char '{' beginning operand 1 `{r11'
/tmp/hello-c8aebe.s:30: Error: no such instruction: `bx lr'
clang: error: assembler (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

### I have installed gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7 and use the following way to compile, but the instruction dose not match.

```
clang -emit-llvm -c hello.c -o hello.bc
llc -march=arm hello.bc -o hello.s
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o hello hello.s
```

fialed in the last command

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of "what targets the compiler supports", but the tools you need to go along with your compiler. It's a bit like complaining at your tool shop that your socket set was able to get the wheel of your car, but it didn't come with a "take tyre off the rim tool".

Clang can generate code for many different processors. But it will depend on external tools to produce binary code from assembly [although I think at least sometimes, it will do that via internal assembler] and to link the binary object files [always, no matter what].

You need `binutils` for your target architecture - at least `as` and `ld` that supports `arm-none-eabi`. Unless your code is also completely standalone, you will need a C-library and a C++ library built for that target.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried a new way to compile but it did not work too. I want to know how to generate the correct asm instructions . 'clang -emit-llvm -c hello.c -o hello.bc
llc -march=arm hello.bc -o hello.s
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o hello hello.s
fialed in the last command:
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o hello hello.s
/usr/local/gcc-linaro-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: error: hello uses VFP register arguments, /tmp/cc65HjLb.o does not
`

Comment: So you are mixing calling conventions - VFP registers vs. no VFP registers. I'm pretty sure you need `-mtriple=...`, but what should go into `...`, I'm not sure - perhaps `arm-linux-gnueabihf`? I expect using `-v` on the gcc command will help a little bit.

Comment: I use arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v to find this "--target=arm-linux-gnueabihf",so I tried to use `llc -march=arm -mtriple=arm-linux-gnueabihf hello.bc -o hello.s`, but I get the same error with VFP registers.